# PHP - Timestamp Issues [LDAP]

Tags: php, datetime, ldap

I have searched endlessly online and still can't seem to get the correct answer for my query.

In PHP I am pulling the whenCreated ldap attribute of a user and it is coming out in the format below:

```
echo $user["whenCreated"]
//20150915110643.0Z
```

This user was created on 15th September 2015 at 11:06:43

I then want to add 1 day to this and insert it into the accountExpires attribute.

The issue I am having is converting timestamps, performing the addition of 1 day, then converting back.

From this site: http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php there appears to be a calculator (which, unfortunately, doesn't show the function used.)

However, it is saying that the format is `YMD LDAP TIMESTAMP` so `YYYYMMDDHHMMSST. T`

I know that with a UNIX timestamp it is easy enough to add 1 day.
So, when I use the following to convert to UNIX Timestamp from an answer on StackOverflow:

```
$winSecs       = (int)($user["whenCreated"] / 10000000); // divide by 10 000 000 to get seconds
$unixTimestamp = ($winSecs - 11644473600); // 1.1.1600 -> 1.1.1970 difference in seconds
echo date(DateTime::RFC822, $unixTimestamp);
```

I get the following output:

> Sat, 16 May 09 05:09:39 +0200

So any help on correct formatting etc. for these timestamps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need. Adds 1 day to supplied date in $ldap

```
$ldap = '20150915110643.0Z';
$convert = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymdhis.0Z', $ldap );
$convert->add( new DateInterval( 'P1D' ) );
$ldap = $convert->format( 'Ymdhis' ).'.0Z';
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks William - this does exactly as I wanted. It was the Zulu formatting part that threw me.